# Offline Nuget Packages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I need to install Nuget Package ProductionStackTrace, so I use the following command

```
PM> Install-Package ProductionStackTrace
```

But when I execute this command I get the following error

> The source at Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages] is unreachable.

I checked the path and yes the package is not there; isn't Nuget Package added by default? If not, from where I can add it?

Comment: this  may help http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/adding-package-source-in-visual-studio-2015/

Comment: You need to add "nuget.org" source if it's missing. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69045231/350384) answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Visual Studio provides some common packages for us to use in the Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages folder when our computer doesn't have network.**

The C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\ folder is not means that the cache for the packages has been installed before from internet. So the package ProductionStackTrace will not add into this folder.

If you want to use this package without network, you need to download it when you have network. You can download it from the [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ProductionStackTrace/).

Certainly, you can also add this package in to the Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages so that you can use it when you do not have a network. The add command line is:

```
nuget add <packagePath> -source <sourcePath> [options]
```

You can refer to the nuget [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference#add) reference for detail.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio for Mac, any idea where those packages could be located on that platform?

Comment: @rraallvv in case you didn't find the answer for your question, I added an answer below.

Answer (score 16):

Unclear why this happened for my installation, but Visual Studio (VS 2022 preview at this time) had an offline location (good), but **no package source to nuget**.

This caused my build to fail on packages not found in the offline directory.

Hence I ended up adding a  `Package source` in Visual Studio for Nuget as:

```
 nuget.org
 https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

Which then allowed VS to do a `Restore` of packages to succeed.

So, I did **not** have to do a `nuget install Newtonsoft.json -source ...` type command on each failed package, as mentioned in other posts.

Comment: Thanks for posting the URL for nuget.org.  I recently installed VS 2022 Community on a new laptop. After cloning my source and opening in VS, my NuGet package source was inexplicably set to Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages.  I had to click the green plus sign and add nuget.org using address you have above. Then all packages restored.  I've coded in VisualStudio for 15+ years, but compared to NPM or Golang pkg source, NuGet still leaves a lot to be desired.

Answer (score 7):

for Visual Studio Mac, packages are copied into the path `/Users/{username}/.nuget/packages`

You can choose menu for Visual Studio->Preferences->Nuget->Sources and add a new source using this path and install already cached packages.

Comment: Thanks. I think back then I figured it out (or someone pointed that to me), but it's good to have it documented somewhere. ;)

Comment: I found that this path *also* exists on Windows.  I found the nuget packages I'm using on the node connected to the internet here.  Not 100% sure if moving them will work on the node that doesn't have internet.

Answer (score 1):

manually dowload from nuget.org package with extension NUPKG file,and copy paste that into (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages) relative path
OR
RUN CMD COMMAND:

dotnet add projectpath package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore --version 6.0.0

Comment: *THIS* is the type of solution I was looking for.  I need to get the files from a node with internet access and move it to tree on the node without internet access.

Comment: Was is `projectpath`? I want to install this package in the nuget source `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages` so it's available for all projects.?
And you cannot just download the package to this folder (you can "install" it using the nuget command, but this it what we want to avoid)