# NuGet package sources missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to install a package that's on nuget.

This one: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NAudio/

When I follow this guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio
about how you add packages to your project I'm stuck at 2) since I only have "Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages" available as a source.

This is a new WPF project on a fresh install of VS.net 2019 community edition.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In Visual Studio, can you check NuGet sources? Tools -> Options -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Sources. It should have "nuget.org" source.

Comment: @vernou There's only one source in there and it's Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages

Answer (score 84, accepted):

As vernou already mentioned there must be also `nuget.org` inside the list. If it's not there you can easily add it through the green plus in the upper right corner.

[image: nuget-options]

The name is *nuget.org* (but of course you can name it whatever you want) and the source *must* be **https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json**. After adding this entry you should be able to find the package on nuget.

Comment: It wasn't there but adding that specific URL did work. Cheers.

Comment: This works, but why in the world is the nuget.org package source missing on a fresh Visual Studio install?!

Comment: I just had this happen with a fresh install of VS2022 Enterprise. I have probably installed VS 50 times or more in my career and I have never seen this before.

Comment: This just happened to me as well, so odd, VS2022 Enterprise

Comment: Same here. VS2022 Enterprise and this was missing. Seems like a miss on the Microsoft side.

Comment: A co-worker just encountered this problem with VS2022 Enterprise too.

Comment: Same issue here with a fresh new installation of Visual Studio Community 2022

Comment: This just happened to me on a fresh install of Visual Studio 2022: Community Edition. This is crazy. Why did Microsoft take this out?

Comment: Just hit this problem after installing Visual Studio Build Tools 2022 on top of a normal 2022 Professional install. All package sources gone in VS after that. Very weird.

Answer (score 23):

1. Add nuget.org as source

```
dotnet nuget add source "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" --name "nuget.org"
```

2. Verify that this source was added:

```
dotnet nuget list source
```

Answer (score 18):

I found another way to solve it. According to **@zivkan** (GitHub Contributor), the reason is that one of the `nuget.config` files that NuGet tried to open is invalid XML. You can try going to `%appdata%\nuget` and renaming `nuget.config` to something else. The next time NuGet tries to access it, it will re-create the file with defaults.

It worked with me.

Follow the [original answer here](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2617#issuecomment-670060002).

Comment: the real answer.. well at least for me.. the slow answer didn't work

Comment: yes, delete your `%appdata%/NuGet/nuget.config` and then, when you run `dotnet` next time, it will be recreated with the `nuget.org` source.

Comment: This worked for me. As soon as I removed the file, The `Manage NuGet Packages For Solusion` dialog in Visual Studio 2022 immediately updated to show 'nuget.org' as a source. I didn't have to add it to Visual Studio 2022. The `nuget.config` file was automatically created as well. I didn't have to run anything to have it created.

Comment: This worked for me, too!

Answer (score 2):

Adding the NuGet package source via Visual Studio Options dialog will edit the config file in `%appdata%\NuGet\`, which is only effective for the currently logged in user.

**If you want to add a package source for all users**, machine-wide, you have to edit the *.config file that is placed in `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\NuGet\Config\`.

Example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages"
         value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\"/>
    <add key="Enterprise NuGet Packages"
         value="https://enterprise.local:44315/nuget" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

It will be also displayed in the Visual Studio options, but cannot be edited there:

[image: Visual Studio Options dialog]

Answer (score 1):

If we have the nuget CLI, from the command line we can run this:

```
nuget add -Name "nuget.org" -Source "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"
```